optimization problem with constraints using pygmo
I have to solve an optimization problem in Python, I have to minimize the objective function with seven constraints. I am using pygmo, but I have problems with the algorithm, I really do not understand what I am doing wrong. I am trying to realize half an orbit from the Earth to Mars and half an orbit from Mars to the Earth, I have to make sure that the last position and the last velocity of the half of the orbit going forward is equal to the position and velocity of the half of the orbit going backward. The objective function is written in order to maximize the final mass.
I have written the following code:
import numpy as np
import pykep as pk
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pygmo as pg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D




mu_sun = pk.MU_SUN*10**(-9)  #km^3/s^2
r_earth = 1.496e8  #raggio orbitale Terra km
r_mars = 2.279e8   #raggio orbitale Marte km


#orbita di trasferimento Hohmann


a_transfer = (r_earth+r_mars)/2


t_of = 348.79*pk.DAY2SEC


g0 = 9.80665


thrust = 0.5  #N


Isp = 2000   #s


m0 = 1000  #kg


earth = pk.planet.jpl_lp('earth') #effemeridi Terra
mars = pk.planet.jpl_lp('mars')  #effemeridi Marte


r0 = [-140699693, -51614428, 980]  #km lista, propagate lagrangian vuole liste
v0 = [9.774596, -28.07828, 4.337725*10**(-4)]  #km/s


rM = [-172682023, 176959469, 7948912]  #km
vM = [-16.427384, -14.860506, 9.21486*10**(-2)]  #km/s



r_fwd, v_fwd = pk.propagate_lagrangian(r0, v0, t_of/2, mu_sun)  #non so se è giusto, comunque devo vedere se vanno messi qui o no
r_bwd, v_bwd = pk.propagate_lagrangian(rM, vM, -t_of/2, mu_sun)






class Optimization:


   def __init__(self, r_i, v_i, r_f, v_f, m0, Isp, mu, g0, t_of, r_fwd, v_fwd, r_bwd, v_bwd):


       self.r_i = r0
       self.v_i = v0
       self.r_f = rM
       self.v_f = vM
       self.m0 = m0
       self.Isp = Isp
       self.mu = mu
       self.g0 = g0
       self.t_of = t_of
       self.r_fwd = r_fwd
       self.v_fwd = v_fwd
       self.r_bwd = r_bwd
       self.v_bwd = v_bwd


      


   def fitness(self, x):


       mf = x[0]


       constraint_posx = self.r_fwd[0] - self.r_bwd[0]
       constraint_posy = self.r_fwd[1] - self.r_bwd[1]
       constraint_posz = self.r_fwd[2] - self.r_bwd[2]


       constraint_velx = self.v_fwd[0] - self.v_bwd[0]
       constraint_vely = self.v_fwd[1] - self.v_bwd[1]
       
       
       `constraint_velz = self.v_fwd[2] - self.v_bwd[2]`





       dV_fwd = np.linalg.norm(np.array(self.v_fwd)-np.array(self.v_i))
       dV_bwd = np.linalg.norm(np.array(self.v_bwd)-np.array(self.v_f))


       m_fwd = self.m0*np.exp(-dV_fwd/(self.Isp*self.g0))
       mf = m_fwd*np.exp(-dV_fwd/(self.Isp*self.g0))
       m_bwd = mf*np.exp(dV_bwd/(self.Isp*self.g0))


       constraint_mass = m_fwd-m_bwd


       J = -mf


       constraints = [constraint_posx, constraint_posy, constraint_posz, constraint_velx, constraint_vely, constraint_velz, constraint_mass]


       return [J] + constraints


   def get_bounds(self):


       return([0], [self.m0])
      
   def get_nec(self):
          
       return 7
      
   def get_ni(self):


       return 0
      

prob = pg.problem(Optimization(r0, v0, rM, vM, m0, Isp, mu_sun, g0, t_of, r_fwd, v_fwd, r_bwd, v_bwd))
algo = pg.algorithm(pg.nlopt('slsqp'))
pop = pg.population(prob,10)
pop = algo.evolve(pop)


best_solution = pop.champion_x
mf_final = best_solution


print(mf_final)

Unfortunately, it does not work, I have tried different algorithms, none of them work... can someone help me, please?
